# functions not running

Tags: esp8266, arduino-ide

I have the following code as part of my efforts to clean this all up into more neatly organised functions.

I'm trying to run GetTemperatures and RunSerial as part of the main loop, however neither are being called.

If I uncomment the two code blocks I've tried to migrate into the functions in the main loop and comment out the calling of those two new functions, everything works ok.

I've looked through the arduino documentation and other places online but I'm unable to see where I've gone wrong.

```
#include <OneWire.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <ESP8266mDNS.h>

//#include <DallasTemperature.h>

const char* ssid = "ssid";
const char* password = "password";


//This sketch is for Wemos R1 not Arduino
//Pin Assignment
OneWire  ds(D6);

//Digital Pin 4 Fan PWM pins)
int FanPin = D7; //Pin 4
int FanPWM = 0; //Start fans at max speed
int FanPercent = 100; // PWM power %

//Temperature thresholds

int Set0PCTemp = 26;   // Temp for 0% fan speed
//int MidTemp = 30;   // Max Temp for Min & Min Temp for Max
int Set100PCTemp = 36;   // Temp for 100% fan speed

// Temperature measurements

float MeasTemp;       //Measured temperature value
float DStemp;         //Value extracted from DS18B20 Sensor

// Serial port input values
int In0PCTemp;
int In100PCTemp;


ESP8266WebServer server(80);

void setup(void) 
  {
  //analogWriteFreq(25000);
  pinMode(FanPin, OUTPUT);
  analogWrite(FanPin, 128);
  delay(1000);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  Serial.println("");
  // Wait for connection
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
    {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
    }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("Connected to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  Serial.print("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  if (MDNS.begin("esp8266"))
    {
    Serial.println("MDNS responder started");
    }
    server.on("/", handleRoot);
    server.on("/inline", []()
      {
      server.send(200, "text/plain", "this works as well");
      }
              );
    server.onNotFound(handleNotFound);
    server.begin();
    Serial.println("HTTP server started");
    //wifi end
    }

void handleRoot()
  {
  //declare CSV variables
  String CSVHeaders = "Set0PCTemp,Set100PCTemp,MeasTemp,FanPercent,FanPWM";
  String CSVMessage = "";
  String CSVPayload = "";
  //  Compile CSV variables
  //CSVMessage = Set0PCTemp + "," + Set100PCTemp + "," + MeasTemp + "," + FanPercent + "," + FanPWM;
  CSVMessage += Set0PCTemp;
  CSVMessage += ",";
  CSVMessage += Set100PCTemp;
  CSVMessage += ",";
  CSVMessage += MeasTemp;
  CSVMessage += ",";
  CSVMessage += FanPercent;
  CSVMessage += ",";
  CSVMessage += FanPWM; 
  CSVPayload = CSVHeaders;
  CSVPayload += "\n";
  CSVPayload += CSVMessage;
  //  char CSV_Payload[] = CSVPayload;
  //notify serial port of HTTP request
  Serial.println( "Sending Readings");
  Serial.println(CSVPayload);
  server.send(200, "text/plain", CSVPayload);
  }

void handleNotFound()
  {
  String message = "File Not Found\n\n";
  message += "URI: ";
  message += server.uri();
  message += "\nMethod: ";
  message += (server.method() == HTTP_GET)?"GET":"POST";
  message += "\nArguments: ";
  message += server.args();
  message += "\n";
  for (uint8_t i=0; i<server.args(); i++)
    {
    message += " " + server.argName(i) + ": " + server.arg(i) + "\n";
    }
  server.send(404, "text/plain", message);
  }

void GetTemperature ()
  {
    Serial.println("step1");
  //original
  byte i;
  byte present = 0;
  byte type_s;
  byte data[12];
  byte addr[8];
  float DStemp;
  //////
  if ( !ds.search(addr)) 
    {
    Serial.println("step2");
    ds.reset_search();
    delay(250);
    return;
    } 
  if (OneWire::crc8(addr, 7) != addr[7]) 
    {
    Serial.println("CRC is not valid!");
    return;
    }
    // the first ROM byte indicates which chip
    switch (addr[0]) 
      {
      case 0x10:
      type_s = 1;
      break;
      case 0x28:
      type_s = 0;
      break;
      case 0x22:
      type_s = 0;
      break;
      default:
      Serial.println("Device is not a DS18x20 family device.");
      return;
      }
    Serial.println("step3");
    ds.reset();
    ds.select(addr);
    ds.write(0x44, 1);        // start conversion, with parasite power on at the end  
    delay(1000);
    present = ds.reset();
    ds.select(addr);    
    ds.write(0xBE);         // Read Scratchpad
    for ( i = 0; i < 9; i++) 
      {           
      data[i] = ds.read();
      }
    // Convert the data to actual temperature
    int16_t raw = (data[1] << 8) | data[0];
    if (type_s)
      {
      raw = raw << 3; // 9 bit resolution default
      if (data[7] == 0x10) 
        {
        raw = (raw & 0xFFF0) + 12 - data[6];
        }
      } 
    else 
      {
      byte cfg = (data[4] & 0x60);
      if (cfg == 0x00) raw = raw & ~7;  // 9 bit resolution, 93.75 ms
      else if (cfg == 0x20) raw = raw & ~3; // 10 bit res, 187.5 ms
      else if (cfg == 0x40) raw = raw & ~1; // 11 bit res, 375 ms
      }
  DStemp = (float)raw / 16.0;
  }

void RunSerial()
  {
        Serial.print(Set0PCTemp);
    Serial.print(",");
    Serial.print(Set100PCTemp);
    Serial.print(",");
    Serial.print(DStemp);
    Serial.print(",");
    MeasTemp = DStemp;
    //control fan speed
    //if(MeasTemp < Set0PCTemp) 
     //{ 
     // if temp is lower than minimum temp
       //FanPWM = map(DStemp, Set0PCTemp, Set100PCTemp, 255, 0); // the actual speed of fan
       FanPWM = map(DStemp, Set0PCTemp, Set100PCTemp, 1023, 0); // the actual speed of fan
       //FanPWM = constrain(FanPWM, 0, 255);
       FanPWM = constrain(FanPWM, 0, 1023);
       analogWrite(FanPin, FanPWM);  // spin the fan at the fanSpeed speed
       //FanPercent = map(FanPWM,0,255,100,0);
       FanPercent = map(FanPWM,0,1023,100,0);
       Serial.print(FanPercent);   
       Serial.print(",");
       Serial.println(FanPWM);   
       //Serial.println(CSVMessage);
       //} 
       //take temperature threshold input
      while (Serial.available() > 0)
        {
        int In0PCTemp = Serial.parseInt();
        int In100PCTemp = Serial.parseInt();
        if (Serial.read() == '\n')
          {
          In0PCTemp = constrain(In0PCTemp, 20, 35);
          In100PCTemp = constrain(In100PCTemp, 35, 50);
          Serial.print("Min=");
          Serial.print(In0PCTemp);
          Serial.print(",");
          Serial.print("Max=");
          Serial.print(In100PCTemp);
          Serial.println();  
          Set0PCTemp = In0PCTemp;
          Set100PCTemp = In100PCTemp;
          }
      }
  }

void loop(void) 
  {
    GetTemperature;
  //start of GetTemperature content
  /*
  Serial.println("step1");
  //original
  byte i;
  byte present = 0;
  byte type_s;
  byte data[12];
  byte addr[8];
  float DStemp;
  //////
  if ( !ds.search(addr)) 
    {
    Serial.println("step2");
    ds.reset_search();
    delay(250);
    return;
    } 
  if (OneWire::crc8(addr, 7) != addr[7]) 
    {
    Serial.println("CRC is not valid!");
    return;
    }
    // the first ROM byte indicates which chip
    switch (addr[0]) 
      {
      case 0x10:
      type_s = 1;
      break;
      case 0x28:
      type_s = 0;
      break;
      case 0x22:
      type_s = 0;
      break;
      default:
      Serial.println("Device is not a DS18x20 family device.");
      return;
      }
    Serial.println("step3");
    ds.reset();
    ds.select(addr);
    ds.write(0x44, 1);        // start conversion, with parasite power on at the end  
    delay(1000);
    present = ds.reset();
    ds.select(addr);    
    ds.write(0xBE);         // Read Scratchpad
    for ( i = 0; i < 9; i++) 
      {           
      data[i] = ds.read();
      }
    // Convert the data to actual temperature
    int16_t raw = (data[1] << 8) | data[0];
    if (type_s)
      {
      raw = raw << 3; // 9 bit resolution default
      if (data[7] == 0x10) 
        {
        raw = (raw & 0xFFF0) + 12 - data[6];
        }
      } 
    else 
      {
      byte cfg = (data[4] & 0x60);
      if (cfg == 0x00) raw = raw & ~7;  // 9 bit resolution, 93.75 ms
      else if (cfg == 0x20) raw = raw & ~3; // 10 bit res, 187.5 ms
      else if (cfg == 0x40) raw = raw & ~1; // 11 bit res, 375 ms
      }

    //Display current values
    DStemp = (float)raw / 16.0;
    */
    //end of GetTemperature content
    RunSerial;
    //start of RunSerial content
    /*
    Serial.print(Set0PCTemp);
    Serial.print(",");
    Serial.print(Set100PCTemp);
    Serial.print(",");
    Serial.print(DStemp);
    Serial.print(",");
    MeasTemp = DStemp;
    //control fan speed
    //if(MeasTemp < Set0PCTemp) 
     //{ 
     // if temp is lower than minimum temp
       //FanPWM = map(DStemp, Set0PCTemp, Set100PCTemp, 255, 0); // the actual speed of fan
       FanPWM = map(DStemp, Set0PCTemp, Set100PCTemp, 1023, 0); // the actual speed of fan
       //FanPWM = constrain(FanPWM, 0, 255);
       FanPWM = constrain(FanPWM, 0, 1023);
       analogWrite(FanPin, FanPWM);  // spin the fan at the fanSpeed speed
       //FanPercent = map(FanPWM,0,255,100,0);
       FanPercent = map(FanPWM,0,1023,100,0);
       Serial.print(FanPercent);   
       Serial.print(",");
       Serial.println(FanPWM);   
       //Serial.println(CSVMessage);
       //} 
       //take temperature threshold input
      while (Serial.available() > 0)
        {
        int In0PCTemp = Serial.parseInt();
        int In100PCTemp = Serial.parseInt();
        if (Serial.read() == '\n')
          {
          In0PCTemp = constrain(In0PCTemp, 20, 35);
          In100PCTemp = constrain(In100PCTemp, 35, 50);
          Serial.print("Min=");
          Serial.print(In0PCTemp);
          Serial.print(",");
          Serial.print("Max=");
          Serial.print(In100PCTemp);
          Serial.println();  
          Set0PCTemp = In0PCTemp;
          Set100PCTemp = In100PCTemp;
          }
      }
      */
      //end of RunSerial content
      //wifi
      server.handleClient();
  }
```

Comment: Do you know you have to use "()" after the name of a function? Like `getTemperature()` instead of `getTemperature`

Answer (score 2):

```
RunSerial;
```

that does not call the function. Instead you should do

```
RunSerial();
```

same with `GetTemperature`

Comment: Anything you write in C++ is happily accepted by the compiler, even when it make no sense at all. And people thinks that C/C++ is a good choice for learning programming.

Comment: Depends on the compiler warning level, of course ... `warning: statement is a reference, not call, to function 'getTemperature' [-Waddress]`

Comment: @JaromandaX. Please, tell me what `char (a) = 10;` means. That "()" baffles me.

Comment: What does that have to do with the code in the question?

Comment: *Anything you write in C++ is happily accepted by the compiler, even when it make no sense at all.* - anything? I doubt it. C++ compilers have been tightening up code validation for a while now.

Comment: Please, someone explain me what is the case use for `RunSerial;` statement. I can't see how this is not an error. Between undefined behavior, implementation dependent features and lack of context free grammar, C++ is a ugly beast.

Comment: @LookAlterno simplification of the grammar & semantics, but you can use the identifier of the function on it own to assign to a function pointer: `fooPtr = RunSerial;`

Comment: @ratchetfreak. That I know, but what is the semantic of a reference floating alone in the source code? How can be that not an error?

Comment: @LookAlterno it's a nop. you can use `(void) var;` to silence a unused local variable warning though.

Comment: @ratchetfreak Deleting that unused local variable is the right way to do. C++ is feature creep.